# Как преобразовать отрицательно число в положительное, и наоборот?

Tags: java

У меня есть переменная

```
int pYaw = (int) mc.thePlayer.rotationYaw;
int pPitch= (int) mc.thePlayer.rotationPitch;
```

pYaw может возвращать отрицательно или положительное число, но как мне преобразовать отрицательно число в положительное, и наоборот?

Comment: Math.abs()  и -Math.abs()

Comment: умножить на -1.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не работает((

Comment: @splash58 а как наоборот? оно всегда изменяется то в минус то в плюс

Comment: может вам что-то другое нужно,  преобразует отрицательное в положительное и наоборот как раз умножение на - 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поставь минус(-) перед выражением.

```
int pYaw = -(int) mc.thePlayer.rotationYaw;
int pPitch= -(int) mc.thePlayer.rotationPitch;
```

либо умножить на `-1` – как писал Алексей Шиманский

Answer (score -2):

```
System.out.println(yaw / -1 + " - " + pitch / -1)
```

идею дал @АлексейШиманский, примерил я